# Oracle SQL - compare date with range of dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with compare one date from partition by product_id. I need to check whether last date_to ordered by date_to desc is between date_from and date_to in range of dates.

Here's example of partition:

**product_id** | **date_from** | **date_to**

```
 1     | 2017-01-01| 2019-05-01
 1     | 2017-04-15| 2017-06-10
 1     | 2017-03-15| 2017-03-25
 1     | 2017-01-19| 2017-02-01
```

How can I check whether date in last row is between any range of date in partition by product_id. This order have to be intact. I tried to with LAG function but it will check only previous range, I tried with min(date_from) and max(date_to) even here will be problem because min is from first row and max from the second and the qualification is false because I need to check every range of dates by product not whole range. The solution will check:

*2017-02-01 between (first row of partition) 2017-01-01 and 2019-05-01 (TRUE)

*2017-02-01 between (second row of partition) 2017-04-15 and 2017-06-10 (FALSE)

*2017-02-01 between (third row of partition) 2017-03-15 and 2017-03-25 (FALSE)

Result: YES! The date is between some range of dates ;) OK just flag 1 will be enough :)

I will be grateful for any help you can provide and sorry for my english :)

**EDIT:**
Current problem is how to check every date_to in order with previous range. E.g.

(second date_to) 2017-06-10 between (first row) 2017-01-01| 2019-05-01

(third date_to) 2017-03-25 between (first row) 2017-01-01| 2019-05-01 and (third date_to) 2017-03-25 between (second row) 2017-04-15| 2017-06-10

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       CASE WHEN first_value( date_to ) OVER (Partition by product_id Order by date_to )
                 BETWEEN date_from AND date_to
                 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
       END As my_flag
FROM table1 t1
ORDER BY date_to DESC
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b351f/4

```
| PRODUCT_ID |             DATE_FROM |               DATE_TO | MY_FLAG |
|------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|---------|
|          1 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00.0 | 2019-05-01 00:00:00.0 |       Y |
|          1 | 2017-04-15 00:00:00.0 | 2017-06-10 00:00:00.0 |       N |
|          1 | 2017-03-15 00:00:00.0 | 2017-03-25 00:00:00.0 |       N |
|          1 | 2017-01-19 00:00:00.0 | 2017-02-01 00:00:00.0 |       Y |
```

Comment: It looks quite nice! I will try it. And do you have any idea how to check every date_to with previous range? For example date from second row compare with first, third compare with first and second and the last one compare with first, second and third...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH results AS (
  SELECT
    t.product_id,
    max(case when t.min_date_to BETWEEN t.date_from AND t.date_to
      then 1
      else 0
    end) AS result
  FROM (
    SELECT
      x.*,
      min(x.date_to) over (partition by x.product_id) AS min_date_to
    FROM
      your_table x
  ) t
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  x.product_id,
  r.result
FROM
  your_table x
JOIN
  results r ON r.product_id = x.product_id;
```

The result will be as follow:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | RESULT  |
|------------|---------|
|        111 |       1 |
|        222 |       1 |
|        333 |       0 |
|        444 |       1 |
|        554 |       0 |
```

This query checks minimum `date_to` of every product with previous date ranges for that specific product. As a result you get '1' for those products which have minimum `date_to` matches at least one date range for this product, or '0' - in other case.

Comment: Look at my comment on next post please.

Comment: Added minor change to the query: max function for the 'results' CTE. Please take a look.

Comment: Vadym thanks for your message, but this still compare only min_date_to and now I need to check every date with previous range date_from and date_to. Correct procedure will compare secodn date from date_to and compare it with previous range. Next take third date from date_to and compare with range from first row and compare with second range... I added edit to my question.